# Getting 500 http error on requesting access token OAuth2 Spring implementation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

This is the sequence of question [Problems redirecting to access token entry point Oauth Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443582/problems-redirecting-to-access-token-entry-point-oauth-token).

I have had help on fixing some of it but I am now having an error with authorization/permission while getting to /oauth/token. I am using Spring 4.0.5.RELEASE, Spring-Security 3.2.5.RELEASE and now Spring-Oauth2 2.0.4-build in place of 2.0.3.RELEASE.

The error is the following and I suspect I have something wrong either with the entry-point security or the oauth2:authorization-server.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is error="access_denied", error_description="Error requesting access token."

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is error="access_denied", error_description="Error requesting access token."
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:66)
```

Here is my authorization-server setup:

```
<oauth2:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="webServiceClientService" 
    token-services-ref="tokenServices" user-approval-page="/oauth/userapproval" 
    error-page="/oauth/error" authorization-endpoint-url="/oauth/authorize" 
    token-endpoint-url="/oauth/token" user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler" 
    redirect-resolver-ref="resolver">
    <oauth2:authorization-code
        authorization-code-services-ref="codes" />
    <oauth2:implicit/>
    <oauth2:refresh-token/>
    <oauth2:client-credentials/>
    <oauth2:password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager"/>
</oauth2:authorization-server>
```

My userAuthenticationManager for password is:

```
<sec:authentication-manager alias="userAuthenticationManager"> 
<sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService"> 
<sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/> 
</sec:authentication-provider> 
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

where userService is an implementations of UserDetailsService.

For the pattern="/oauth/token" I have access="hasAuthority('OAUTH_CLIENT')" to which I have defined on the user roles.I also have for session create-session="stateless" and my authentication-manager-ref="oauthClientAuthenticationManager". The oauthClientAuthenticationManager has as authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" which is UserDetailsService implementation.I have entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" which is org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoin‌​t and not changing realm or TypeName.

I also have . clientAuthenticationEntryPoint is also a OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint but I have typeName set as Basic while the Realm reamins the default oauth.

I also set

```
<sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" /><sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" /> 
<sec:expression-handler ref="webSecurityExpressionHandler" />
```

Where clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter is org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpoi‌​ntFilter with oauthClientAuthenticationManager as an authentication manager.

```
<sec:authentication-manager id="oauthClientAuthenticationManager"> 
<sec:authentication-provider user-serviceref="clientDetailsUserService"> </sec:authentication-provider> 
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

I also have

```
<sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" /> 
<sec:expression-handler ref="webSecurityExpressionHandler" />
```

oauthAccessDeniedHandler = org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler. 
And webSecurityExpressionHandler = org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2WebSecurityExpress‌​ionHandler

Also my entry point is as follows:

```
<sec:http use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="oauthClientAuthenticationManager"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" pattern="/oauth/token">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="hasAuthority('OAUTH_CLIENT')" />
    <!-- <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" /> -->
    <!-- <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"/> -->
    <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <!-- <sec:http-basic/> -->
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    <sec:expression-handler ref="webSecurityExpressionHandler" />
    <!-- <sec:custom-filter ref="corsFilter" after="LAST"/> -->
</sec:http>
```

Where the clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter is defined as:

```
<beans:bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="oauthClientAuthenticationManager"/>
</beans:bean>
```

And

```
<sec:authentication-manager id="oauthClientAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService">
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="webServiceClientService" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Is there any suggestions on it? Thanks.

Comment: The stack trace is from the client app right? What about the Auth server (the one that hosts the /oauth/token endpoint)?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your Spring version Spring 4.0.5.RELEASE, Spring-Security 3.2.5.RELEASE. Check Spring 4.0.5 is suitable with Spring-Security 3.2.5. I think you should down grade your Spring 4.0.5 to 3.xx.xx.

Comment: Not the case Thuta. They are compatible and work fine.